# Trying to block content in a div tag from Monday to Friday; from 0900 to 1600 only

Tags: javascript

```
<p id="showDate"></p>

<script>
    var a = moment().format('ddd Do MMMM'); $('#showDate').html(a); 
</script>

this.element.find('div[data-content-uuid=""]').css('display','block');
```

This is what I have come up with so far

Comment: Hey friend, it is not easy to understand what you're really trying to accomplish. Please elaborate your question a little more as well as use the formatting tools to make it more readable.

Comment: share your full code

Comment: Trying to block content in a div tag. However the user still need access after 1600 each day and over the weekends. The above script work but blocks the entire div all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
var day = moment().get('day'); //Get day, 1 = Monday, 5 = Friday
var hour = moment().get('hour');

if((day > 0 && day < 6) && (hour >= 9 && hour <= 16 )){ //If it's inside the timespan...
    $('#showDate').html(value); //Value is what you want to type inside the div
}
```

Comment: When you say value are you talking about the content uuid??

Comment: Whatever you want to write inside your div!